# Поиск по "словам через запятую"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имеется в базе данных записи у них есть поле `data` оно с таким содержимым `random_word,random_word,random_word,random_word`

random_word - любое слово их количество может быть любым

надо вывести из таблицы те записи у которых одно из этих "random_word" совпадает с переменной `$word`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table where concat(',',data,',') like '%,$word,%'
```